# Log-in to Spring/Angular project from a struts Application

Tags: spring, angular, struts2

I have an existing struts application to which an angular/spring application will be combined. Both will exist on different url patterns. But both will be having a same login page which is a jsp. Also, spring security is used in the angular/spring application.

Based on the logged in user, from the login, the user will be redirected to either angular-spring/struts application and the authentication will be done by the respective applications. So I need to send the username and password to angular and then do the login from there.
But I am not able to send the data to angular side and even if I can somehow, Im not sure how to retrieve the data. How can I achieve this ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write rest API so you can get or post data from angular app
Hope this post will help you  https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-springboot-angularjs-bootstrap-springdata-j